# Accessing protected method from other instance with same parent class in typescript

Tags: typescript, oop, protected

I'm porting code from PHP to NodeJs (Typescript).
And i came across the following PHP code (simplified)

```
<?php
class A {
    protected function protectedData() {
        return 'accessible';
    }
}
class B extends A {
    public function extractTest($anInstanceOfA) {
        return $anInstanceOfA->protectedData();
    }
}
$instanceA = new A();
$instanceB = new B();
echo $instanceB->extractTest($instanceA);
```

Running it in a sandbox results in an echo "accessible".

I wrote the same code in Typescript, but that does not seem to work...

```
class A {
  protected protectedData(): string {
    return 'accessible';
  }
}

class B extends A {
  public extractTest(anInstanceOfA: A): string {
    return anInstanceOfA.protectedData();
  }
}

const instanceA = new A();
const instanceB = new B();


console.log(instanceB.extractTest(instanceA));
```

> Error: Property 'protectedData' is protected and only accessible through an instance of class 'B'.(2446)

Is there a way to achieve this in Typescript or is there a big difference between protected methods in PHP and Typescript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#understanding-protected):

> The protected modifier acts much like the private modifier with the exception that members declared protected **can also be accessed within deriving classes**.

In above case, you use `protectedData` as method from a function parameter `anInstanceOfA`, that happens to be of base type `A`. But you don't access `protectedData` *within* deriving class `B` by `this.protectedData()`, so TS yells here. What works and what not:

```
class B extends A {
  public extractTest(anInstanceOfA: A, instanceOfB: B): string {
    anInstanceOfA.protectedData() // ✖, protected member of arg with base class 
    instanceOfB.protectedData() // ✔, protected member of arg with *same* class 
    this.protectedData(); // ✔, (derived) protected member via `this`
    return anInstanceOfA["protectedData"]() // escape-hatch with dynamic property access
  }
}
```

So you either can declare `protectedData` as `public` or use an escape-hatch, which will make `protected` members accessible via dynamic property access with bracket notation.

```
anInstanceOfA["protectedData"]()
```

[Playground sample to try it out](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=99&ssl=20&ssc=58&pln=15&pc=1#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)